# Kendo row highlighting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a kendo template and following is the code to highlight the selected row.

```
kendo.data.binders.index = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
    refresh: function () {
        var value = this.bindings["index"].get();
        if(viewModel.currentRow != null){
            $(".row-select").find('span').css("box-shadow", "");
            $(".row-select :input").filter(function(){ return this.value == value +1 }).parent().find('span').css("box-shadow", "0 0 5px 2px #357EBD");
        }
    }
});
```

Sometimes it selects two rows. I need to avoid that.
Instead of this.value, I need to get RowIndex value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure out the problem.

`$(".row-select :input")` to `$(".row-select :rowIndex")`

Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Adding index to limit filtered rows to Single row.

```
kendo.data.binders.index = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
    refresh: function () {
        var value = this.bindings["index"].get();
        if(viewModel.currentRow != null){
            $(".row-select").find('span').css("box-shadow", "");
            $(".row-select :input").filter(function(){ return this.value == value +1 })[0].parent().find('span').css("box-shadow", "0 0 5px 2px #357EBD");
        }
    }
});
```